# Kernighan and Ritchie. Example on Copying Characters

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw

I am learning C with a book "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie. On the topic **1.5.1 File Copying** there is an example of copying input characters with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{

    int c;

    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);

}
```

**The question is:** why if I send into input only one line of characters (for example "abc" and then press "CTRL + Z" to end a file), the program will not display anything. If I send few lines it displays everything correctly.

**Additional Info:** I use Eclipse Luna CDT with MinGW.

Comment: Maybe there is buffering and you want to call fflush(stdout) after the while loop.

Comment: Kernighan and Ritchie writes "program that copies its input to its output one character at a time". 
In my case that program doesn't copy characters. I try to understand why and how to make this code to work correctly.

Comment: The problem is probably that you are interacting with a console. You are correctly writing the data into the console buffer with the "putchar" function. But then the console gets to decide what to do. Most consoles will only write complete lines i.e. they write the buffer content only when they see a newline ('\n'). So the the program does copy characters one at a time, but only into the buffer of a different program (your console). This behavior might be slightly different for your specific environment.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'll test this program in different environment. I'm going to set up Ubuntu.

Comment: Control-Z must be on a line of its own, followed by a newline. Otherwise it is not an EOF.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand one thing here, until the `EOF` occurs your `while((c=getchar()) != EOF)` will be true! When you give the input `CTRL + z`, it is `EOF` so that time your `while` condition will fail, it wont execute the statement next to the condition.

```
while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) // when it fails
    putchar(c); // it wont be executed.
```

How `while` will fail?

When you give input `a`, the variable `c` will get `a` and it will check with `EOF`, now the condition is true, so it will wait for next char and so on. when you press enter after giving some input, it will display he output!

Say input- `abcdef` and `Enter`, when you press enter, `c` holds the value of `Enter`, so this case `c != EOF` true, so it executes `putchar(c);`!

Output- `abcdef`

But when you give like this- `abcde` and `CTRL + z`, when you press `CTRL + z`, `c` holds `EOF`, so this case `c != EOF` condition fails, so i wont execute `putchar(c);`. so you will get nothing on the screen.

If you want change your code like this and try-

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{

    int c;

    while (c=getchar()) // when you press CTRL + z also it will work
    putchar(c);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is running fine.
The thing is when you provide the input, all the characters are stored inside a buffer, and the buffer will be printed on the screen when you hit 'enter'(return) i.e. the contents of the buffer are not printed until a newline character('\n') is pushed into the buffer.
Therefore if you press "CTRL + Z" before hitting return, nothing will be displayed on the output screen.